# Why is this simple Google Maps code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am using version 3.8 *without* a key. I have used this exact code before (with no key) from my desktop and it worked just fine, but now it is not working for some reason.

I can't find any typos, has the import declaration without a key changed from what I am using?

Here is my stripped-down code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdfasdf</title>
    </head>
    <body onload = "initialize();">

        <!-- map here -->
        <div id = "map"></div>

        <!-- Google Maps API -->
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;sensor=true&amp;v=3.8"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">

            function initialize()
            {
                // object literal for map options
                var myOptions =
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891), // coordinates for center of map 30, 3
                    zoom: 4, // smaller number --> zoom out
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN, or HYBRID
                };

                // note: if the id has a dash in its' name, map instantiation doesn't work!
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            } // end of initialize
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;sensor=true&amp;v=3.8

to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true&v=3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's working. maybe you forgot to give `width/height` for you map div so you cannot see it ?

you can have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/2HmMQ/

Comment: Haha, that's exactly right! Duh, I can't believe I missed that one, sometimes I really get stuck on the simple things. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

[V3.8 is retired](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), if you request it you will get v3.9.

Your problem is your map doesn't have a size, so you can't see it.

If I change your map div to give it a size, something like this:

```
        <div id="map" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
```

It works.